# ¿Cómo puedo modificar en python código de un módulo de terceros?

Tags: python, rasa-nlu

Quiero modificar un paquete, [rasa_nlu](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/), pero no sé cómo probar un paquete modificado porque, por ejemplo cuando hizo `from rasa_nlu` creo que es el que se descargó en los requisitos.txt

Comment: He respondido a lo que planteas al final: _No sé cómo probar un paquete modificado porque aquí cuando from rasa_nlu creo que es el que se descargó en los requisitos.txt_, que creo que es la pregunta que querías hacer. En ese caso el título de la pregunta debería ser cambiado a algo como "¿Cómo puedo modificar en python código de un módulo de terceros?" o similar

Comment: @abulafia Ha muchas gracias! Pero en verdad estaban las preguntas. El segundo fue cómo salieron estas warnings que me gustaría cambiar.

Comment: Creo que con la respuesta dada tienes las herramientas necesarias para buscar tú mismo la causa. De cualquier modo resulta casi imposible que otro pueda hacerlo por tí, pues no tenemos tu aplicación ni la posibilidad de reproducir el error.

Comment: Esto puede ser relevante: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162506/undefinedmetricwarning-f-score-is-ill-defined-and-being-set-to-0-0-in-labels-wi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que usas un entorno virtual para instalar los paquetes (¡siempre recomendable!) puedes, con el entorno activado, usar lo siguiente para averiguar dónde quedó instalada la biblioteca que te interesa:

```
(flaskenv) $ python3
>>> import rasa_nlu
>>> rasa_nlu.__file__
'/ruta/absoluta/a/flaskenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasa_nlu/__init__.py'
```

Una vez que sabes la ruta al paquete que te da problemas, puedes entrar en esa carpeta y empezar a investigar en su código fuente, e incluso modificarlo. Cada vez que, desde el entorno virtual activado, hagas `import rasa_nlu` se usará la versión modificada. Si estropeas algo siempre puedes crear un entorno virtual nuevo e instalar de nuevo los paquetes para que todo vuelva a funcionar como al principio.

Ten en cuenta no obstante que, si estás ejecutando pruebas en un Jupyter Notebook o IPython o cualquier otro intérprete interactivo, cuando haces `import rasa_nlu` por primera vez será cuando se lea del disco el módulo y se ejecute. Posteriores ejecuciones de `import rasa_nlu` no lo leerán de nuevo (python mantiene una diccionario con los módulos que ya ha leido para no volver a leerlos).

Si andas haciendo cambios en el código del módulo y quieres "recargarlo", volver a ejecutar la celda que tiene el `import` no funcionará. Ante esto tienes dos alternativas:

- Reiniciar el intérprete (el kernel en el caso de Jupyter)
- Usar la siguiente receta:

```
import rasa_nlu
import importlib
importlib.reload_module(rasa_nlu)
from rasa_nlu import ...
```

**Nota** El truco anterior requiere Python 3.5 o superior.

### Otra posibilidad

Si pretendes contribuir al desarrollo de `rasa_nlu` (o de cualquiera que sea el módulo de terceros que estés modificando), la estrategia preferible sería esta otra:

1. Abre una cuenta en Github y úsala para hacer un *fork* del repositorio donde estaba el paquete original (https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu)
2. Crea una carpeta en tu máquina de desarrollo y clona en ella repositorio de Github (no el original, sino el tuyo, consecuencia del *fork* anterior).
3. Con tu entorno virtual activado, desinstala el módulo en cuestión (`pip uninstall rasa_nlu`) que borrará del entorno virtual la versión que habíamos instalado vía Pypi, pues queremos usar en su lugar la versión de desarrollo.
4. Con tu entorno virtual activado entra en la carpeta creada en 2. Asegúrate de que contiene un `setup.py` y dentro de ella pon `pip install -e .`

El paso 4 vuelve a instalar `rasa_nlu`, pero instala la versión que has bajado de Git (pues a `pip install` le mandas instalar lo que hay en esa carpeta al darle `.` como nombre de paquete). Además, gracias a la opción `-e` lo instalas en modo "editable", que significa que lo que instala en el entorno virtual no es una copia del paquete, sino un enlace simbólico a la carpeta de desarrollo.

La consecuencia de lo anterior es que, si ahora haces `import rasa_nlu`, lo que se importará es la versión de desarrollo que has descargado en el punto 1, en lugar de la versión estable habitualmente descargada de Pypi.

A partir de aquí puedes usar Git para controlar los cambios que vayas introduciendo en el paquete, de modo que a medida que hagas cambios que consideres válidos puedes añadirlos (`git push`) a tu copia en Github del repositorio.

Si llegas a un final satisfactorio en el que resuelves un bug y quieres contribuir con tu solución al paquete original, usa la interfaz web de Github para hacer un *pull request* al autor. Éste recibirá las modificaciones (*commits*) que hayas hecho en tu repositorio desde que hiciste *fork* del original. El autor puede examinar los cambios que hayas hecho y si está de acuerdo con ellos, mezclarlos con su propio repositorio. ¡Habrás contribuido!

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo ingresar a la carpeta creada en 1 en el paso 3? ¿Rehago un clon git del tenedor?

Comment: Pienso que hay un error aqui *El paso 3 vuelve a instalar rasa_nlu* ¿te refieres al paso 4 no?

Comment: @Marine1 Sí, perdona, había un baile de números porque al principio había puesto sólo tres pasos, y después añadí el paso 1 renumerando los demás, pero me quedó alguno sin cambiar. Creo que ya está arreglado.

Comment: @Marine1 De todas formas, mirando otra vez tu pregunta  con más detalle (la versión anterior que tenía ejempos de código), veo que el módulo que te está dando los _warnings_ es sklearn, así que todo lo explicado en la respuesta deberías hacerlo sobre el repositorio <https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn> en lugar de `rasa_nlu`. Cabe esperar que si primero instalas sckit-learn con `pip install -e .` desde el repositorio clonado, cuando luego instales `pip install rasa_nlu` éste verá que sklearn ya está instalado y no bajará otro de Pypi.

Comment: En verdad, no pensé en modificar `sklearn` pero `rasa_nlu` buscando lo que llamaba `sklearn` y tratando de atrapar con un try catch el warning, esto me permitiría dejar el nombre del  intent `rasa`que no tiene suficientes ejemplos.

Comment: Si lo único que quieres es que no se vean esos warnings, tal vez desaparezcan si pones un `import warnings;
warnings.filterwarnings('always')` antes de los restantes `import`, sin necesidad de tocar nada en módulos de terceros.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81185/discussion-between-marine1-and-abulafia).

Answer (score 0):

Solo para actualizar la información sobre la librería importlib. Para recargar un modulo ahora se utiliza de la siguiente forma

```
import rasa_nlu
import importlib
importlib.reload(rasa_nlu)
from rasa_nlu import ...
```

En vez de

```
import rasa_nlu
import importlib
importlib.reload_module(rasa_nlu)
from rasa_nlu import ...
```